NameError using multiprocess pool with function which calls another function
I would like to use multiprocessing in my jupyter notebook and AFAIK, the multiprocess package is the way to to that. My function does quite a lot of stuff, so it calls multiple subfunctions, but this throws a NameError for the name of the subfunction, unless the subfunctions are defined in the function beein called.
import multiprocess as mp

def test_int():
    return 1

#This throws import multiprocess as mp
def test_int():
    return 1

#This throws "NameError: name 'test_int' is not defined"
def test():
    return test_int()

#This works
def test2():
    def test2_int():
        return 2
    return test2_int()

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    with mp.Pool(20) as pool:
        for _ in range(20):
            res = pool.apply_async(test, [])
            print(res.get())

As the functions are defined before the process is started and even before the called function is defined, I don't see a reason why this wouldn't work, but it doesn't.
The second varient works for now, but gets messy fast with more and bigger functions, so is there a way to make this cleaner?

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

code works correctly on my Linux Mint. But I didn't test it in jupyter-notebook

I tested in jupyter-notebook and it works for me too.
